# FirebasePerformance SDK external library issue in proguard

Tags: android, performance, android-proguard, firebase-performance

I have implemented`FirebasePerformance` SDK to measure app performance. It is working fine in debug mode without `proguard` but giving issue of an external library used in my application when trying to generate a signed build using `proguard`.

Getting following issue:

> java.io.IOException: Can't read [F:\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\FirebasePerformancePlugin\debug\folders\1\2\7776c3fca671135b87737cd2d8b26538-sessionkeygenerator(;;;;;;**.class)] (F:\MyApp\app\build\intermediates\transforms\FirebasePerformancePlugin\debug\folders\1\2\7776c3fca671135b87737cd2d8b26538-sessionkeygenerator\META-INF\maven\com.sdl.skey\sessionkeygenerator.jar (Access is denied))

Here `sessionkeygenerator.jar` is an external library I am using to encrypt my data in `XML` format.

Comment: Is sessionkeygenerator.jar being used in your debug build? That error message appears to be at the file system level, where the jar is not readable by the Firebase Performance plugin. There shouldn't be a difference between debug/release.