# Android FirebasePerformance issue with Proguard

Tags: android, android-proguard, firebase-performance

We implemented FirebasePerformance in our project and when are unable to build the project. I get below error in Proguard which has something to do with having a two classes with same name but different cases (A.class and a.class) in the external library (qrchart_obfuscation.jar). I am not very familiar with proguard also.

Reading thru sources, I am looking to add -dontwarn option in proguard but this will be my last resort since sources says to "use it only when you know what you are doing".

I still tried to add `-dontwarn qr.android.chart` and I compared Mapping.txt with my previous builds which does not have FirebasePerformance and I see a difference on the class (qr.android.chart) not sure if this detail helps

Appreciate your help and suggestions with proguard setup for FirebasePerformance.

```
Reading program directory [C:\...\build\intermediates\transforms\FirebasePerformancePlugin\adevelop\release\4] (filtered)

Warning: class [qr/android/chart/b/a.class] unexpectedly contains class [qr.android.chart.b.A]
Warning: class [qr/android/chart/b/b.class] unexpectedly contains class [qr.android.chart.b.B]
Warning: class [qr/android/chart/b/c.class] unexpectedly contains class [qr.android.chart.b.C]
Warning: class [qr/android/chart/b/d.class] unexpectedly contains class [qr.android.chart.b.D]
Warning: class [qr/android/chart/b/e.class] unexpectedly contains class [qr.android.chart.b.E]
Warning: class [qr/android/chart/b/f.class] unexpectedly contains class [qr.android.chart.b.F]
Warning: class [qr/android/chart/b/g.class] unexpectedly contains class [qr.android.chart.b.G]
Warning: class [qr/android/chart/b/h.class] unexpectedly contains class [qr.android.chart.b.H]
Warning: class [qr/android/chart/b/i.class] unexpectedly contains class [qr.android.chart.b.I]
Warning: class [qr/android/chart/b/j.class] unexpectedly contains class [qr.android.chart.b.J]
Warning: class [qr/android/chart/b/k.class] unexpectedly contains class [qr.android.chart.b.K]

Warning: there were 11 classes in incorrectly named files.
         You should make sure all file names correspond to their class names.
         The directory hierarchies must correspond to the package hierarchies.
         (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#unexpectedclass)
         If you don't mind the mentioned classes not being written out,
         you could try your luck using the '-ignorewarnings' option.
```

I saw this link with regards to Firebase performance and proguard issue during build of signed APK but different case -[FirebasePerformance SDK external library issue in progaurd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49398991/firebaseperformance-sdk-external-library-issue-in-progaurd)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the qr.android.chart library isn't using the dontusemixedcaseclassnames option when proguarding.

When building on a case insensitive file system (i.e., that Mac OSX likes to use), the byte code instrumentation process Firebase Performance uses runs into issues because the unarchived classes end up overwriting each other.

Your options are to either disable byte code instrumentation or ask for a new qr.android.chart library with the dontusemixedcaseclassnames option activated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on macOS, I've found an ugly workaround for this. Create a case sensitive disk image and copy the project there, so firebase perf plugin can handle the case sensitive files.

How to create the disk image here: https://documentation.spryker.com/tutorials/howtos/ht-case-sensitive-file-system-mac.htm

For my project I needed a 5gb image.